# Implementing a shortcut into a text line in Word automation

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I have a word document which have tables. These tables have links which explain structure of the table. 1 to 1 is available in word for going forth and back by hyperlinks but i have x to 1 link. I can link from x table to 1 explanation but can not link back from 1 to x for obvious reasons. So there is a shortcut for it, when you click the link then use ALT + LEFT ARROW it return to original point. But i need to implement this into something that user do not need to know the shortcut and just click and return back. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution for this. Only far workarounds, useless for this question neverthless.